# Screen of Asus zenbook freezes

Tags: 22.04, freeze, asus

I have an Asus Zenbook (Model: UX3402Z) with Ubuntu 22.04 installed.

Constantly the picture freezes. There is no apparent reason. (Sometimes it frees after 1-2 hours, sometimes only after several hours)

Sometimes it works again and sometimes I have to hold the power button until it goes off.

When I write and the PC freezes, it continues to "work". At least he continues to write the letter that I have pressed when he is frozen

This looks like this

```
Hello Worl <freezes>

<unfreezes> Hello Worllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll
```

Unfortunately, I can't see any log entries that would show the cause.

Every time it freezes I write down the time (with seconds). But never is anything in the log

This is of course annoying, and really bad when I have unsaved things.

That's why I'm unfortunately already thinking about switching to WIndows, which wouldn't be nice but at least it works. :/

There are several drive problems, maybe this is the reason?

These are today's log entries until he is frozen again

```
10:08:39 kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
09:27:12 bluetoothd: src/profile.c:ext_io_disconnected() Unable to get io data for Hands-Free Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
08:42:40 canonical-livep: daemon shutting down
08:42:11 gdm-session-wor: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
08:42:10 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
08:42:08 gdm-session-wor: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
08:42:01 canonical-livep: Task "refresh" returned an error: livepatch check failed: POST request to "https://livepatch.canonical.com/v1/client/12e37b0605c546bc9c4df4ca96e92dac/updates" failed, retrying in 30s.
08:42:01 bluetoothd: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
08:42:01 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
08:42:00 kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: PPM init failed (-110)
08:42:00 gnome-session-b: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL: g_bus_get_sync: assertion 'error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed
08:42:00 kernel: acpi INTC1048:00: Get fan state failed
08:42:00 kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.H_EC.TFN1._FST due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20220331/psparse-529)
08:41:59 kernel: cs35l41-hda spi1-CSC3551:00-cs35l41-hda.1: error -EINVAL: Platform not supported -22
08:41:59 kernel: tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead
08:41:59 kernel: pci 0000:00:07.2: DPC: RP PIO log size 0 is invalid
```

```shell
$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy



$ sudo lshw -c video

  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=2560x1600 resolution=2560,1600 visual=truecolor xres=2560 yres=1600
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:179 memory:603e000000-603effffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff



$ printf 'Desktop: %s\nSession: %s\n' "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "$GDMSESSION"

Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
Session: ubuntu
```

I had already read about similar things and e.g. disabled the hardware acceleration of chrome, has brought nothing

Can anyone tell me what the problem may be, does anyone have the same?

## Edit (05/25/23)

There were a few updates yesterday and today.

Today there was not a single freeze.

I'll look at it for a few more days and get back to you.

## Edit (06/01/23)

There were a few more updates, until now everything runs without problems

## Edit (06/06/23)

Sometimes it freezes, but after a few seconds it works again. There is still nothing in the logs.

So it has become much better (probably due to updates). But there are still problems with the freezing.